Wordpress: Reuse sections of post on another Wordpress post without hurting SEO
I have wine "trip reports" that are long Wordpress posts that contain stories about visiting specific wineries. Each trip report post is sturctured chronologically and each winery has its own section. I've got multiple trip report posts from multiple years (2023,2022,etc.) often revisiting wineries I have visited before. For example:
2023 Trip Report

Winery A
Winery B
Winery C

2022 Trip Report

Winery A
Winery D
Winery E
Winery F

I would like to create a Wineries Page where i can write some historical information about the winery, and then include the sections from the trip reports posts that I've written about my visits to that particular winery. For example:
Winery A Page
[Blub about the history, etc.]

2023 Visit to Winery A (from above)
2022 Visit to Winery A (from above)

I'd like to basically reuse sections from the Trip Reports posts on the Wineries Pages without impacting SEO.
Ideas on how best to easily accomplish this?
Thanks
